# program should ask for items to put into the shopping list. If the input is '0 ' the program should stop,printing the contents of the shopping list

Tags: python

Add new item to shopping list: mango

Add new item to shopping list: cucumber water

Add new item to shopping list: pineapple

Add new item to shopping list: beef

Add new item to shopping list: 0

Items on your shopping list are:

mango, cucumber water, pineapple, beef

```
while True:
    word = input("Add new item to shopping list: ")

    if word.isalpha() == True:
        break
    else:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, in the StackOverflow community, it’s not customary to ask people to solve your problems. It is much better to formulate a question and ask.

Here's your code:

```
cart = []

s = input()
while s != '0':
    cart.append(s)
    s = input('Add new item to shopping list: ')

print(', '.join(cart))
```